# ExtJs 2.0 form moves in Chrome 39 when is filling or press 'Tab' key

Tags: forms, google-chrome, extjs, tabs, move

Someone knows why my form is moving when I press 'Tab' key or I edit it when it's filled ?

This only happens in Chrome 39, in old versions works OK and in Firefox or IE works fine too.

Thanks !! It's seems that the css is the same before and after fill the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it fixing the width of the text fields to fit the content.

Answer (score 1):

If the version is not a typo, Ext JS 2.0 was released 7 years ago in Dec 2007 when Chrome still had one year to go before its initial release. Hence, you cannot expect a good compatibility of the old library with modern browsers.

Nevertheless, if the problem appears only in one version 39 of Chrome and the application is most likely that it is the problem of that specific version. You can report it to Chrome development team but I don't think that anything beyond that is worth the effort.

Fixing and changing that old application can be more costly, depending on size, than upgrading it to the latest Sencha libraries.